# Cassandra CPU usage to be considered healthy?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

A question to people having a Cassandra Cluster in production: Until when do you treat a Cassandra node being healthy from a CPU usage POV? E.g. some sort of average CPU usage threshold (or Unix load) for a certain time period?

We are currently running a 6-node test cluster and apply some sort of our load patterns and we are seeing e.g. an average CPU usage of ~ 45-60% for the last day on each node. No scheduled/explicit read repair during that time. Is this already asking for extending the cluster with additional nodes or can this be considered as being healthy?

Answer (score 1):

I would start to seriously consider expanding the cluster when my *peak* cpu (or disk i/o) hits 80% of capacity for more than a few seconds.  So if your load is very constant you're probably fine, but looking at just the daily average isn't enough detail to say for sure.

Comment: How does that match with the coloring of the Load (CPU) column in the Cluster list view in OpsCenter? In our test load pattern with the 6-node Cluster we are constantly below 4 on each node with some spikes at ~ 5 when minor compactions are occurring. Does the coloring take the number of available CPUs/Cores on the node into account?

Comment: OpsCenter takes the load average reported by the machine, divides it by the number of cores, and uses that number to determine the color of the node. Less than 1 is green. 1-5 is yellow, and more than 5 is red. Hope that helps.